# Why is my str_replace returning values after the replaced value?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to extract video URLs from the source of an HTML file but it's replacing my value but printing everything after it

```
$url = 'http://www.SITE.com/categories/redhead';
$url2 = 'http://www.SITE.com/';
$search = file_get_contents($url);
$results = explode('"/movies?id=', $search);

$final = $url2 .$results[2];
$goodfinal = str_replace('">', ' ', $final);
echo $goodfinal.'<br>';
```

Comment: Stop using string parsing, use the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument).

Comment: +1 for @Brad: Don't complain that the hammer you're using is breaking things, when you should be using a scalpel.

Comment: @MarcB - That sounds like a fortune cookie.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, could you explain it to me in a PM?  I haven't coded in a while so I'm trying to relearn php.

Comment: `DOMDocument` , then either `getElemetsByTagName()` or a more elaborat `DOMXPath`, `getAttribute`, then you can use `parse_url` & `parse_str`. I also refuse to guess what that site is about.... :P

Comment: @Wrikken obviously a bird-watching site, with categories like `redhead` for the red-headed woodpecker.

Comment: Hehe. A lot of birdwatching sites nowadays have API's... isn't that an option on that particular one?

Comment: Nope, your not really supposed to be ripping the bird documents